Figma to Webflow Plugin 'getting stuck' when updating/Styling components
It seems as though I can use the 'Design System Sync' option to copy single components, but when I try to sync something like my Nav bar (4 Components), it freezes. It gets stuck on 'Updating component styles...'.

I've refreshed the page several times, I've logged out of Webflow, I've tried opening Webflow through the Plugin on the Figma side, it always freezes. Is there an element or Style that the Plugin just doesn't recognize, so it freezes? Or is there a different issue?  I can still close the plugin, even back out of it so it doesn't freeze the browser. It just seems like it stops doing anything.
